# Can operator overloading solve the compiler error when calling a function with pointers to a vector of vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void JoinRows(double *C, double *A, int nrows, int ncols, double *B, int mcols);
// Function to join two matrices by rows
void JoinRows(double *C, double *A, int nrows, int ncols, double *B, int mcols) 
{
   for (; nrows > 0; nrows--) { 
      memcpy( C, A, sizeof(double) * ncols );
      C += ncols;
      A += ncols;
      memcpy( C, B, sizeof(double) * mcols );
      C += mcols;
      B += mcols;
   }
}

int main() {    
  unsigned int i, j;
  double elem = 0.0;
  unsigned int nrows {4}, ncols {3}, mcols {2}; 
  double A[4][3];
  double B[4][2];
  double C[4][5];
  // Declare matrices to be used as a vector of vectors
  vector<vector<double> > AMatrix, BMatrix, CMatrix;
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    vector<double> ROW1;
    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
      ROW1.push_back(elem);
      if (j == (ncols)) {
        ROW1.push_back(elem);               
      }
    }
    AMatrix.push_back(ROW1);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    vector<double> ROW2;
    for (j = 0; j < mcols; j++) {
      ROW2.push_back(elem);
      if (j == (mcols)) {
         ROW2.push_back(elem);              
      }
    }
    BMatrix.push_back(ROW2);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    vector<double> ROW3;
    for (j = 0; j < (ncols+mcols); j++) {
      ROW3.push_back(elem);
      if (j == (ncols+mcols)) {
        ROW3.push_back(elem);               
      }
    }
    CMatrix.push_back(ROW3);
  } 
  printf("Prog: TestJoinRows.c - JoinRows() in the file JoinRows.c\n");
  printf("\n");
  // Initialize A //
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) 
      {
        A[i][j] = (double) (4 * i + j);
        AMatrix[i][j] = (double) (4 * i + j);
  }
   // Initialize B //
   for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < mcols; j++) 
     {
      B[i][j] = (double) (2 * i + j + 1);
      BMatrix[i][j] = (double) (4 * i + j);
 }
  // Print A //
  printf("A\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) printf("%6.1f",AMatrix[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
  // Print B //
  printf("B\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < mcols; j++) printf("%6.1f",BMatrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n\n"); 
  // Print C //
  printf("C\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (ncols+mcols); j++) printf("%6.1f",CMatrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n\n");

  printf("Call JoinRows\n\n");
  // The function using arrays
  JoinRows(*C, *A, nrows, ncols, *B, mcols);
  // The function using vectors
  JoinRows(&CMatrix[0][0], &AMatrix[0][0], nrows, ncols, &BMatrix[0][0], mcols);

  // Print C //

  printf("C the join of A and B along rows\n");

  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (ncols + mcols); j++) printf("%6.1f",C[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n\n");

  // Print CMatrix //

  printf("CMatrix the join of A and B along rows\n");

  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < (ncols + mcols); j++) printf("%6.1f",CMatrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n\n");


  // Print A after calling JoinRows(). //

  printf("A after call to JoinRows().\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) printf("%6.1f",A[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
  } 
  printf("\n\n\n");

  // Print B after calling JoinRows(). //

  printf("B after call to JoinRows().\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < mcols; j++) printf("%6.1f",B[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
  } 
  printf("\n\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I am declaring arrays using vectors in the standard template library. However, when I attempt to call a function with parameters using pointers, I receive the following error:
free(): invalid next size (fast)
Aborted (core dumped)
Can operator overloading correct the memory error when I call the function? Thank you.`

Comment: This is an awful lot of pointers for allegedly C++ code. PSA: Use arguments of type `const std::vector&` instead of pointer/size pairs.

Comment: The error you describe is not a "compiler error".  That is a runtime error, which happens when compilation succeeds, but there is a problem while the program is running.  Your `JoinRows` function is writing to invalid memory.

Comment: The wild mixing and matching of vector, 2D arrays, pointers, irregular cases on function names, and more is making this code really hard to follow. Functions are typically lower-case first, if not all lower-case, as in `joinRows` or `join_rows`. Likewise, `ROW1` implies it's a constant, which it clearly is not. In fact, given there's `ROW2`, what you want is `std::vector<std::vector<double>> rows`.

Comment: If these are fixed-length rows, you could even use `std::array` if that feels better.

Comment: You have a bug in your code, operator overloading is not the solution, fixing the bug is the solution. The code would be simpler (and so any bugs would be easier to spot) if you just used vectors. There is no need for the arrays and pointers.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the style of your code that you learned C programming first, and are now adding some C++. But C++ is not really an add on to C, it's a whole different language. What's good programing in C, is not good programming in C++.

Comment: Minor point: there's no need to write a function declaration immediately before its definition. A definition is a declaration, so once the compiler has seen the definition it knows what the function's signature is. Get rid of `void JoinRows(double *C, double *A, int nrows, int ncols, double *B, int mcols);`.